# Changes are sometimes not saving with sublime/gulp

Tags: sass, gulp, gulp-watch

I have a wordpress installation and creating a theme based on a lynda.com tutorial (WordPress: Building Themes from Scratch Using Underscores).

I installed gulp and all the needed stuff to work with scss but the problem is sometimes, changes don't save!
http://prntscr.com/o60i1a

the file is changed and watch is starting but the scss file is not updating.

The problem is sometimes it works when I close cmd or browser!

I read in another question here that you need to add this to sublime:

"atomic_save" : true

I did it, and it worked so changes are now saving okay (I was happy) but this mourning it's not saving again : (

Gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    // Prepare and optimize code etc
    autoprefixer = require('autoprefixer'),
    browserSync = require('browser-sync').create(),
    image = require('gulp-image'),
    jshint = require('gulp-jshint'),
    postcss = require('gulp-postcss'),
    sass = require('gulp-sass'),
    sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps'),

    // Only work with new or updated files
    newer = require('gulp-newer'),

    // Name of working theme folder
    root = '../' + themename + '/',
    scss = root + 'sass/',
    js = root + 'js/',
    img = root + 'images/',
    languages = root + 'languages/';


// CSS via Sass and Autoprefixer
gulp.task('css', function() {
    return gulp.src(scss + '{style.scss,rtl.scss}')
    .pipe(sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(sass({
        outputStyle: 'expanded', 
        indentType: 'tab',
        indentWidth: '1'
    }).on('error', sass.logError))
    .pipe(postcss([
        autoprefixer('last 2 versions', '> 1%')
    ]))
    .pipe(sourcemaps.write(scss + 'maps'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(root));
});

// Optimize images through gulp-image
gulp.task('images', function() {
    return gulp.src(img + 'RAW/**/*.{jpg,JPG,png}')
    .pipe(newer(img))
    .pipe(image())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(img));
});

// JavaScript
gulp.task('javascript', function() {
    return gulp.src([js + '*.js'])
    .pipe(jshint())
    .pipe(jshint.reporter('default'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest(js));
});


// Watch everything
gulp.task('watch', function() {
    browserSync.init({ 
        open: 'external',
        proxy: 'localhost/wp',
        port: 8080
    });
    gulp.watch([root + '**/*.css', root + '**/*.scss' ], ['css']);
    gulp.watch(js + '**/*.js', ['javascript']);
    gulp.watch(img + 'RAW/**/*.{jpg,JPG,png}', ['images']);
    gulp.watch(root + '**/*').on('change', browserSync.reload);
});


// Default task (runs at initiation: gulp --verbose)
gulp.task('default', ['watch']);
```

Comment: I know a similar behavior from Atom too. You can make changes in the editor, but as long as you don't save them, watch doesn't get triggered. Is this your issue, does a manual save solve your problem and start the watch task ?

Comment: I got starting scss and finishing scss and then reloading browser but the changes are not saved in the end : (

Comment: did you cleared the Browser cache when you refresh? And checked your local compiled css file if the changes are shown ?

Comment: trying incognito window works, I can see the changes, but again now I'm changing the file and running watch, incognito window is auto reloading but the new change is not saving again.

Comment: @FloriandeVille yes it's a cache problem, thank you. I solved this now by disabling cache on Chrom from network tab: http://prntscr.com/o613mh